# XML. SAX . Attributes with default value

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I process XML files using SAX :

```
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", Boolean.TRUE);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I load a grammar (XSD) and set it to the reader.

```
reader.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/grammar-pool", grammarPool);
```

The grammar contains defaultValue for some optional attribute of some element.
Those attributes having default value are passed with this value to the startElement(ContentHandler#startElement)) method from my handler even if they are not present in the source XML. 
Could I somehow verify whether the attribute is present in XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SAX2 parser that reports the feature flag `http://xml.org/sax/features/use-attributes2` as `true` will provide instances of the [`Attributes2`](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/Attributes2.html) interface to the [`Attributes`](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html) argument of `ContentHandler#startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)`. This extended interface provides, among others, the methods `isSpecified(int index)` and `isSpecified(String qName)`, which test `true` if the attribute was specified in the document, or `false` if the value is defaulted through the DTD or schema.

An use case I found was to transduce from XHTML 4.01 Transitional to (X)HTML5 in an EPUB 3.0.1 pipeline. One snag I hit was that the Transitional DTD has the `<br>` element default the attribute `clear` to `none`; this attribute is *invalid* in HTML5. In order to avoid manually filtering all invalidated attributes in HTML5, I rebuild an `Attributes` by filtering defaulted attributes as follows:

```java
public static Attributes filterDefaults(Attributes attributes) {
    // Either test the feature flag, or do an instance test
    Attributes2 attrs = (Attributes2) attributes;
    Attributes2Impl newAttrs = new Attributes2Impl();
    for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
        if (attrs.isSpecified(i)) {
            final String qName = attrs.getQName(i);
            final String type = attrs.getType(i);
            final String value = attrs.getValue(i);
            newAttrs.addAttribute(null, null, qName, type, value);
        }
    }
    return newAttrs;
}
```

The `XMLReader` should be set up to validate both the DTD or schema and the input XML, more or less as follows:

```java
/**
 * @see "https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html"
 */
private XMLReader buildParser(SAXParserFactory parserFactory) throws SAXException {
    try {
        final SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
        final XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        if (!reader.getFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-attributes2"))
            throw new SAXException("SAX2 parser with Attributes2 required");

        // Set your callback instances here
        reader.setEntityResolver(/*...*/);
        reader.setErrorHandler(/*...*/);
        reader.setContentHandler(/*...*/);
        reader.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", /*...*/);

        reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
        reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
        reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);

        return reader;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new SAXException("Can't build parser", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the list of default features that are on/off? I am looking at SAXParserFactoryImpl but cant see it

Comment: The only such listing I was able to find is on Apache's [Xerces 2 site](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html).

Answer (score 3):

That's how default values for attributes are supposed to work.  If you need to distinguish the two cases (defaulted vs. explicitly specified but with the default value) then you'll have to remove the default from the schema and apply it at the code level instead.