# Modify xml attributes with SaxParser

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I have an XML and inside it I want to modify for specific nodes the **value** of **link** attribute using SAXParser.

I did found https://stackoverflow.com/a/51662488/9681353 and I used Attributes2Impl for my case.

What I have so far:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

UpdateLinksHandler linksHandler = new UpdateLinksHandler();
saxParser.parse(xml, linksHandler);
```

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String key, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(USEROBJECT)) {
            String link = attributes.getValue("link");
            if (link != null) {
                Attributes2 attrs = (Attributes2) attributes;
                Attributes2Impl newAttrs = new Attributes2Impl();
                for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
                    if (attrs.isSpecified(i)) {
                        String type = attrs.getType(i);
                        String value = attrs.getValue(i);
                        String name = attrs.getQName(i);
                        if (name == "link") {
                            value = modifyLink(value);
                        }
                        newAttrs.addAttribute(null, null, name, type, modifyLink(value));
                    }
                }
                super.startElement(uri, key, qName, newAttrs);
            }
        }
```

But I don't know if my approach is correct or how I should get my modified xml. Or SAXParser is just for reading purposes?

Thanks

Comment: The SAX parsing part will read your XML, not write it. If you have a schema for the XML documents, and the documents are of predictable size and you know you have sufficient memory, then it is probably easiest to use JAXB to load the documents into a DOM, change the DOM and then marshall the DOM back into an XML string. Alternatively you could use a StAX parser like Woodstox which lets you copy "events" read from an input stream directly to an out stream.

Comment: Thanks! And I did tried in the meantime Java DOM Parser, this worked as well.